# Is ECDSA not available for KeyFactory BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm getting the following exception when I'm trying to get KEyFactory instance of ECDSA 
**java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: ECDSA KeyFactory not available**

I'm trying in this way

```
X9ECParameters curve = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256r1"); 
ECPoint point = curve.getCurve().decodePoint(decode(PublicKey));
pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA")
                   .generatePublic(
                       new ECPublicKeySpec(point,
                           new ECParameterSpec(curve.getCurve(),curve.getG(),curve.getN(),curve.getH())
                       )
                    );
```

Comment: Yes, BC provider has ECDSA (also ECDH and ECDHC as well as plain EC) factories since at least 1.42. Are you sure the BC provider is in your provider list, at the time of this call? What happens if you specify it explicitly `getInstance("ECDSA","BC")`?

Comment: I have tried that I got no such Provider as exception

Comment: Then the provider is not in your provider list. Did you (try to) put it there, either by configuring in the `java.security` file, or by calling `java.security.Security.{addProvider,insertProvider}` ?

Comment: Thanks, issue got solved by adding the provider